# MySQL queries in python taking a lot of time, postgres queries work fine

Tags: python, mysql, performance

I am using a time profiler for optimizing my python script. It turns out that mysql queries are taking lot of time in my python scripts. There are total of only 19 queries. These 19 mysql queries take over 7.44 secs as reported by cProfile.

Following is the complete script footprint, with mysql query and respective query time in secs.

```
$ python -m cProfile -s time myscript.py 
MYSQL Queries
SELECT column FROM table WHERE foreign_key = 1 AND somecolumn='val1'
0.378623008728
SELECT column FROM table WHERE foreign_key = 1 AND somecolumn='val2'
0.379124879837
...
SELECT column FROM table WHERE foreign_key = 1 AND somecolumn='val19'
0.377450942993

   60122 function calls (59599 primitive calls) in 7.634 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       20    7.440    0.372    7.440    0.372 {method 'query' of '_mysql.connection' objects}
       22    0.025    0.001    0.025    0.001 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2._psycopg.cursor' objects}
        2    0.008    0.004    0.008    0.004 {method 'commit' of 'psycopg2._psycopg.connection' objects}
     1299    0.007    0.000    0.011    0.000 posixpath.py:59(join)
      982    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {posix.lstat}
      429    0.006    0.000    0.010    0.000 text_file.py:162(readline)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.006    0.006 {psycopg2._psycopg.connect}
        1    0.006    0.006    0.025    0.025 __init__.py:18(<module>)
        2    0.004    0.002    0.007    0.004 connections.py:62(__init__)
      110    0.004    0.000    0.027    0.000 posixpath.py:344(realpath)
       20    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'store_result' of '_mysql.connection' objects}

...
```

Can anyone help me figure out the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Is the database schema exactly the same? Are MySQL and PostgreSQL built with more or less the same options? Are the database settings similar? Did you try playing around with them?

Comment: No, I am selecting from data from a view. Rest everything is same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you forgot to [create an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on `(foreign_key, somecolumn)` resulting in MySQL needing to perform a full table scan to find the data. You can see this by running with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT column FROM table WHERE foreign_key = 1 AND somecolumn='val1'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried enabling the [slow queries log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) of mysql ?

this log file lists all the "slow" queries that the database engine executes. from this information, you can try explaining the query and see if you don't need to define a specific index on the table you are using.